# Web Scraping PHP

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um Web Scraping em PHP para pegar as informações de lote de leilão deste site https://www.sold.com.br/
Preciso captura as informação em um Array. Porém o array não esta trazendo as informações na ordem que eu quero.
Ele está trazendo todas as datas, depois todos os bens, os tipos e as descrições. Eu preciso que ele agrupe no array DATA, BEM, TIPO e DESCRIÇÃO no mesmo índice, só para depois ir para o próximo índice do array.

```
<?php

require_once "simple_html_dom.php";

  $url = 'https://www.sold.com.br/';
  $hold = array();
  $html = file_get_html($url);
  $i = 0;

  if(!empty($html)) {
   $element = $data = "";

  foreach ($html->find(".container-fluid") as $element) {

      foreach($element -> find(".data")as $data){
        $hold[]["Data"] = trim($data->plaintext); 
      }

      foreach($element -> find(".leilao-tipo-bem")as $tipoBem){
        $hold[]["Bem"] = trim($tipoBem->plaintext); 
      }
      foreach($element -> find(".tipo")as $tipo){      
        $hold[]["Tipo"] = trim($tipo->plaintext);
      }

      foreach($element -> find(".leilao-descricao")as $descricao){      
        $hold[]["Descricao"] = trim($descricao->plaintext);
      }
  $i++;
  } 

}
  print_r($hold);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver!!!

Ajustei alguns detalhes no código e alterei o nome da classe no primeiro

```
<?php

require_once "simple_html_dom.php";

  $url = 'https://www.sold.com.br/';
  $html = file_get_html($url);
  $hold = array();
  if(!empty($html)) {
   //$element = $data = "";
   $i = 0;

  foreach ($html->find(".bloco-leilao") as $element) {
    

      foreach($element -> find(".data")as $data){
        $hold[$i]["Data"] = trim($data->plaintext); 
        
        }
      foreach($element -> find(".leilao-tipo-bem")as $tipoBem){
        $hold[$i]["Bem"] = trim($tipoBem->plaintext);
       
        }
      foreach($element -> find(".tipo")as $tipo){      
        $hold[$i]["Tipo"] = trim($tipo->plaintext);
        
        }
      foreach($element -> find(".leilao-descricao")as $descricao){      
        $hold[$i]["Descricao"] = trim($descricao->plaintext);
        
        }
        $i++;
        }
 
  
}

  print_r($hold); exit;

?>
```